# how to use localStorage in react quill?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to achieve autosave user input in react-quill, so when i refresh the page, the user input not disappear.

i put ReactQuill and normal `<input>` in Form, and only `<input>` can work for autosave, the user input in `<ReactQuill/>` can not, why?

```
constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { 
      title: localStorage.getItem('title') || '',
      content:  localStorage.getItem('content') || '' 
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)


handleChange({ target: { name, value }}) {
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
    localStorage.setItem(name, value); 
  }

render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator} = this.props.form;
 return (
    <Form onChange={this.handleChange}>

    <Form.Item
       {getFieldDecorator('title', {
            initialValue:this.state.title
     })(
        <Input
         name='title'
        />,
          )}
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item 
        {getFieldDecorator("content",{
            initialValue:this.state.content
          })(
         <ReactQuill 
            name='content'
            modules={Editor.modules}
            formats={Editor.formats}
          />
          )}
      </Form.Item>
```

Comment: < Form > and < Input > is from 'antd'

Comment: Try `react-quill-antd` - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-quill-antd